# Visual Studio editing proj files with NuGet config when solution loads

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm working on a solution with quite a few (20+ projects)

Something has recently changed so that now when I load the solution in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) Visual Studio edits most (but not all of the proj files).

What's going on?  And how can I make it stop?

[image: NuGet changes]